# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' //500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, python-requests

this  is not sending any data from crome extension,i am trying to send json string to the server with mentioned url which says none type object has been returned,

```js
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var ur = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/animal";
 var dat = {"subject":"subject"};
 xhr.open("POST", ur, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         // do something with response
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
};
xhr.send(dat);
```

```
         }
    };
    xhr.send(dat);
```

Comment: The error is happening in the Python script on the server, not in the above code.

Comment: i solved it , theres nothing wrong wth the server,it was tis code all along

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an object with `xhr.send()`, you need to serialize it.

```
var dat = 'subject=subject';
```